# Probability distribution for a limiting value

Tags: distributions, bounds

I have a bunch of measurements $D_1, D_2, ..., D_N$ and their associated uncertainties $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, ..., \sigma_N$. Suppose that the (unknown) true values of the data points are $T_1, T_2, ..., T_N$. I can also calculate for any $C$ and any measured value $D_i$ the probability $P_i(C)$ that $T_i<C$. If the measurement uncertainties are normal then $P_i(C)$ will just be the integral from $-\infty$ to $C$ of a Gaussian, but in principle I can do the same for other PDFs.

The only thing I know about the underlying population from which the $D_i$ were drawn is that there exists some upper limit $C_\text{lim}$ for which all the $T_i<C_\text{lim}$ even though, due to measurement uncertainty, some of the $D_i>C_\text{lim}$. I'd like a sensible way to judge whether a candidate value $C$ for $C_\text{lim}$ is plausible, given the data. At first I thought I should just multiply together all the $P_i(C)$, but I found that this gives me unrealistically high upper limits.

The reason is that if I have many measurements some of their true values will be near $C_\text{lim}$ and, due to noise, will be measured at a higher value. Thus I expect that a candidate $C$ will still be reasonable even if it is slightly lower than a few of the data points. What I'm after is an objective probability, or perhaps a *plausibility*, $Pl(C)$ that all the $D_i$ are consistent with having lower true values. If possible I would like to avoid assuming anything of the underlying population.

I *suspect* the answer I want is $Pl(C)=\exp\left[\dfrac{1}{N}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N \log_e P_i(C)\right]$. It gives me sensible-looking results when I apply it to various mock data sets for which I already know the true $C_\text{lim}$. But I have no explanation for why it should be right. Is it correct? How should I approach a problem like this?

EDITS:

Here is one of my mock data sets. I generated 160 random data points with true values $T_i$ between 5 and 10. Then I simulated measurement error by moving them up or down by a $\sigma=1$ normally distributed random value.  Even though $C_\text{lim}=10$ there are quite a few measured data points above $D_i=10$. I would expect then that $Pl(10)\sim 0.5$ because it is definitely plausible that the true values are all below 10. And I'd expect also $Pl(8)\approx 0$ and $Pl(12)\approx 1$.

[image: Mock data set]

Comment: One problem your calculation will have is that for $C$ large enough, all $C_j > C$ will have essentially the same $Pl(C_j) (=0)$.  Not sure what to do about this, unless you can put a prior distribution on $C$ or learn more about the distribution of the $D_i$ than just that they have an upper bound.

Comment: For very large $C_j,$ I'll have $P_i(C_j) $essentially equal to 1, since all my measured data points will be well beneath it, so my $Pl(C_j)$ will also be 1. This is telling me nothing except that it is highly likely that my true upper bound is somewhere beneath that. I expect $Pl(C)$ as a function of C to look sort of like an error function with the inflection point somewhere near the true upper bound $C_{lim}$

Comment: Would you share your dataset? Is $D_{1}$ a single data point/measurement?  Is $C$ independent of $i$ in $D_{i}$, i.e. $C \ne C_{i}$?

Comment: Is your $P_{i}\left(C\right) = N_{\mu=D_{i},\sigma=\sigma_{i}}\left(C\right)$?

Comment: Could an estimate for $C$ just be $D_{max}+ 2*\sigma_{max}$?

Comment: What do you mean with "the probability $P_i(C)$ that $D_i<C$"? This sounds to me like the $D_i$ is not a measured value, but instead an estimated value (based on measurements). If these subtle details are not written out then it is unclear where this boundary $C$ is being drawn (very simplistic I'd say that $C$ is equal to the maximum measured point. I get your convoluted problem, but it needs to be written out more precise. ).

Comment: I've improved the description of the problem to hopefully make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Quick comment that your expression simplifies to $Pl \left( C \right) = \left( \prod_{i=1}^{N}P_{i} \left( C \right) \right)^{1/N}$

*-- added after the simulation data was posted --*

So if all of the $\sigma_{i}$ are the same, you might try to 'deconvolute' that uncertainty to get at the upper limit.  Say your underlying population of $\{T_{i}\}$ were normal with standard deviation $\Sigma$, then you could estimate $\hat{\Sigma}=\sqrt{s^{2}-\sigma^{2}}$ where $s$ is the variance of the $D_{i}$?

Comment: Yep. In fact that was the form I first thought of it, but I prefer the summing of logs because it seems to give me fewer rounding issues on a computer.

Comment: or you could try a deconvolution by dividing Fourier Transforms ... https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/Deconvolution.html